# JavaFx different way of code

Tags: javafx

I found the following JavaFx code on internet, but I dont know where to run it or what library I have to import. Please help me to understand..

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.animation.transition.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.transition.SequentialTransition;

import javafx.animation.Timeline;

var fillColor: Color.BLUE;

Stage {
    title : "MyApp"
    scene: Scene {
        width: 400
        height: 200
        content: [
                Rectangle {
                x: 10, y: 10
                width: 140, height: 90
                fill: bind fillColor
            }
            ]
    }
}
```

There is no `start` method and `extends Application` class in the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like JavaFX 1.x - it is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very old JavaFX script code.  JavaFX Script and the system to run it are [no longer supported by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#8) (and likely no longer distributed by them either).

Forget you ever saw the JavaFX Script code and the internet site which provided it.  Do not try to understand the JavaFX Script code.

Instead, learn JavaFX using the Java language based on [current resources for Java client technology (Java 8) at the Oracle Java site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).